# How to make a search form background-color hover over input submit and input text at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, hover

I need some help with code. I'm having problems with hover not changing the background-color on two items at the same time. I have input submit  search button next to the input text and i want both of them to change background color when your hover over one of them.

**HTML**

```
<div id="search">
    <form  id="search-form">    
        <input type="text" id="search-text" name="query" value='Leia veebilehelt...' this.value='Leia veebilehelt...';}" /> 
        <input type="submit" id="search-submit" value="" /> 
    </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#search {   /*servs me as a wrapper*/
    margin-right:160px;
    float:right;
    margin-top: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#search-form{
    font-family: Georgia;
    background: #DDDDDD;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #C4C4C4 0%, #EAEAEA 0%, #D3D3D3 100%); /* firefox */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#C4C4C4), color-stop(0%,#EAEAEA), color-stop(100%,#D3D3D3)); /* webkit */
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#search-form #search-text{
    width: 270px;
    float: left;
    height: 31px;
    border: 0;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #C4C4C4 0%, #EAEAEA 0%, #D3D3D3 100%); /* firefox */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#C4C4C4), color-stop(0%,#EAEAEA), color-stop(100%,#D3D3D3)); /* webkit */
    color: #660000;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Georgia;
}
#search-form #search-text:focus{
    outline:none;
    color: black;
    background: #fff;
}



#search-form #search-submit{
    background: url(images/search.png) no-repeat ; /*is a little magnifier picture*/
    border: 0;
    float: right;
    width: 22px;
    height: 27px;
    z-index: 100;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top:5px;
}

#search:hover ~ #search-submit, #search-form:hover  ~ #search-text{
background-color:#fff;}  /*this doesnt work*/
```

The idea lied in using pure CSS/HTML code without JavaScript (because I don't understand JS).

Thank you in advance for any explanation and help.

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/labkitty/TffX3/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#search-submit` is inside `#search`.. so you shouldn't use `~` there.. Same is the case with other one too..

so, edit your css to this:

```
#search:hover #search-submit, #search-form:hover #search-text{
background:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Please try below code

```
#search input:hover, #search input:hover ~ input{
    background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input tag has background-gradient property. You can not overwrite it using only background color try this on hover : -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #fff); /* firefox */